# Sorting out int variables from a .txt file (fstream, c++)

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream, ifstream

I have a .txt file with these this line on the top `'12 4 25 257'` each of the numbers spaced out by a `' '` and the line ends with `'\n'`

I have these variables and a function `getFirstLine`:

```
int A;
int B;
int C;
int D;
```

```
ifstream File("a.txt");
```

```
void getFirstLine(int &A, int &B, int &C, int &D)
{
 int list[] = {A, B, C, D};
    string myText;
    getline(File, myText);
    int size = myText.size();
    cout << size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (myText[i] != ' ')
        {
            list[i] = (int)myText[i] - 48;
            cout << list[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to basically save the first number on A, second on B, third C etc...

I cant seem to get this working sadly :(
Can someone help me with this?

Output should look like:

```
A = 12,
B = 4,
C = 25,
D = 257,
```

Comment: You're roughly on a good path, but as you seem to have already found out, it's super janky. Consider using the standardised parse functions (`std::stoi`), or just directly the extraction operator to pull the numbers.

Comment: what doesn't work? please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Read a line, which you already do. Then put line into an `std::istringstream` which you then use to parse out the numbers. What you're doing now doesn't do anything like you want, it doesn't make any sense, and will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```cpp
std::string line;
std::getline(file, line);
line = line.substr(1, line.length() - 2);
std::istringstream iss(line);
iss >> A >> B >> C >> D;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<vector>
#include<ifstream>

using namespace std; 

    struct pairs
    {
        char ch; 
        int value;
    };
    int main()
    {   
        vector<pairs> store;
        ifstream is("koord.txt"); 
        pairs temp;
        char ch = 'A';
        while (is)
        {
            temp.ch = ch; 
            is >> temp.value; 
            store.push_back(temp);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < store.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << store[i].ch << " " << store[i].value << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

you can use this. But if you read more entries char will overflow. you can use string instead of char.

Comment: by the way, I forgot to increase char. if you add ++ch; after push_back function letters will increase.

Comment: Thanks - this was useful! using a structure actually make sense for what I need to do anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, might not be the most efficient way of doing it but it seems to work. But I will look into `std::istringstream`. It seems like good way to do it.

```
void getFirstLine(int &A, int &B, int &C, int &D)
{
    string myText;
    string temp;
    vector<int> save;
    int size = myText.size();
    getline(File, myText); //get the first line of text not including \n
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, size = myText.length(); i < size; i++)
    {
        temp.push_back(myText[i]); //adds the myTest[i] to the end of temp
        if (myText[i] == ' ')
        {
            save.push_back(stoi(temp)); //stoi(temp) to an int --> push_back appened to save at the end
            j++;
            temp.clear();
        }
        if (i == (size - 1)) //because the end of the line doesnt have a space
        {
            save.push_back(stoi(temp));
            j++;
            temp.clear();
        }
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         cout << "list "<< i << ": "<< save[i] << endl;
     }
     //retruning the values
     A = save[0];
     B = save[1];
     C = save[2];
     D = save[3];
}
```